# Docusign - Setting tabs in HTML documents - concealValueOnDocument

Tags: docusignapi

Need help with using the attribute ConcealValueOnDocument.  Document in the envelope is a html document

Following syntax was tried and it did not work.

`<input name="color" data-ds-type="text" data-ds-role="Signer1" style="width:120px;" concealValueOnDocument="true" />");`

And in the developer console the option is "Hide text with asterisks". I am looking for examples or directions on how to conceal a value when uploading as HTML.

Also is it possible to hide the text box completely when value is entered?

Edited to show how the document is submitted

```
Document document = new Document();
document.setHtmlDefinition(documentHtmlDefinition);
document.setName(signatureRequest.getDocumentName());
document.setDocumentId(signatureRequest.getDocumentId());
....
envelopesApi.createEnvelope(accountId, envelopeDefinition);
```

And the html has appropriate tags for different fields.

Comment: Please edit your question to add how you're sending the html to DocuSign: in the `documentBase64` attribute or in the `htmlDefinition#source` attribute

Comment: Please CHECK (accept) the best answer for each of your questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the tab via inline HTML. Inline HTML can be used to set many tab properties, but not all of them. `concealValueOnDocument` cannot be set via inline HTML. The list is on page [Setting tabs in HTML documents](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/responsive/setting-tabs) in section **Configuring HTML tabs**.

### Solution

Use an **Inline JSON marker** for the tab. See page [Setting tabs in HTML documents](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/responsive/setting-tabs).

#### Example

API request:

```
"textTabs": [
    {
    "name": "color",
    "tabLabel": "signer1Color",
    "width": "120", 
    "concealValueOnDocument: "true"
    }
]
```

Within the HTML:

```
{{ "tabLabel": "signer1Color" }}
```